# Woocommerce Price Text

Tags: php, wordpress, filter, woocommerce, price

I'm trying to make a change to the way the price appears depending on different states.
The objective is that if the product is "Out of Stock" **SOLD** appears instead of price, then, if price is empty **POA** appears instead the price.

If none of the above is checked appears as normally, the price.

I managed to make this after checking a way to change price label:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'wpa83367_price_html', 100, 2 );
function wpa83368_price_html( $price,$product ){
 // return $product->price;
    if(!$product->is_in_stock()){
      return 'SOLD';
    } else {
    if ( !$product->price > 0 ) {
      return 'POA';
    } else {
      return $price;
    }
  }
}
```

This doesnt work. The price disappears. I know something here is wrong, and i aware that maybe the approach is not the right one. Can someone help me with this one?

Comment: It might just be a typo above, but the call back you use (wpa83367_price_html) doesn't match the actual function name (wpa83368_price_html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You always need to return something. I do it sometimes, but in general I try to avoid multiple return statements, it can make it hard to know where things went wrong.

And you had a copy/paste discrepancy in function names. You would have seen that if you developed with [`WP_DEBUG`](https://codex.wordpress.org/WP_DEBUG) enabled.

Revised function:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'wpa83367_price_html', 100, 2 );
function wpa83367_price_html( $price,$product ){
    if(!$product->is_in_stock()){
        $price = 'SOLD';
    } else if ( !$product->price > 0 ) {
        $price = 'POA';
    } 
    return $price;
}
```